# Android fragment won't show up

Tags: android, layout, transactions, fragment, screen

Hi I'm trying to show the fragment I created. I search over the internet for any solution and did not find any.

This is my code:

The lines calls the fragment:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
EditStudent editStudent = new EditStudent();
fragmentTransaction.add(editStudent, "editStudent").commit();
```

`EditStudent` extends `Fragment`. Here is what I returns in `onCreateView` method:

```
public class EditStudent extends Fragment
{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater,
                          ViewGroup container,
                          Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_edit_student, container, false);
    }
}
```

And this is my `activity_edit_student` layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:gravity="left"
android:layoutDirection="ltr"
tools:context="com.nitay.uziel.students.StudentsList"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/studentPicture"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="120dp"
                    android:layout_span="2"/>

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Name: "
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/studentName"
                    android:layout_width="250dp"
                    android:maxLength="20"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="ID: "
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/studentId"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Phone: "
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/studentPhone"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:maxLength="10"/>

            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <ImageButton
            android:background="@drawable/cancel"
            android:id="@+id/cancelStudentButton"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:background="@drawable/confirm"
            android:id="@+id/confirmStudentButton"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

When I click the button that execute all the transaction code, I still see the activity layout instead of the fragment layout. I don't have any exceptions, just the fragment won't show. I also know that the fragment is created successfully, because when I press the back button I pop the fragment from it's stack with this code:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0)
    {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
    else
    {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
}
```

Any idea will be much appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem - the FrameLayout should be inside the layout of the 
activity whom the fragment belongs to

Comment: I honestly don't know :)

Answer (score 0):

Try call another method that contains id of fragment container. For a example `fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragmentContainer,editStudent, "editStudent").commit();`

Comment: share your activity layout

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your frame layout an I'd and pass the fragment to it.

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, editStudent, "editStudent" ).commit();
```